# Удаление максимального элемента из односвязного списка

Tags: c++, стек, односвязный-список

Господа, помогите, не могу расправиться с задачей.

Требуется удалить максимальный элемент из односвязного списка. Вот два варианта функции, ни один не проходит. Разъясните мне, калеке.

```
void delMaxValue(Stack **stck, int maxValue){
    Stack *tmp = NULL;
    do {
        if ((*stck)->info != maxValue) 
            tmp = *stck;
            cout << tmp->info << endl;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        *stck = (*stck)->next;
    } while ((*stck)->next != NULL);
    while (tmp != NULL)
    {
        *stck = tmp;
        *stck = (*stck)->next;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
```

Другой вариант:

```
Stack* deleteMaxValue(Stack *begin) {
Stack *t = begin, *p = begin->next;
for (; p; p = p->next)
    if (p->info > t->info)  t = p;
p = begin;
if (p != t) {
    while (p->next != t)   p = p->next;
    p->next = t->next;
}
else
    begin = t->next;
delete t;
return begin;
```

}

Заранее спасиибо, братва

Answer (score 1):

Идете по списку от начала к концу, храня, кроме максимального значения, предыдущий (по отношению к текущему) элемент. Если текущее значение больше максимального, запоминаете предыдущий элемент. Когда проход по списку закончен, соединяете сохраненный элемент перед максимальным, с тем, что после максимального.

*Проверки предельных случаев (максимальный элемент - первый или последний, пустой список, список из одного элемента и т.п.) оставлены в качестве упражнения для читателя.*

Comment: А если первый и является максимальным, думаете ТС догадается?

Comment: @avp Cтараюсь не считать других дурнее себя :).